# How to catch and manage exceptions for GPS module?

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi using a GPS module. To use the module, I am running a code such as this:

```
##Prints the latitude and longitude every second.
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
    while True:
        data = gps.get_gpgga()
        List = [list(data.values())[x] for x in [7, 9, 12]]
        string=str(List)
        string = string[1:-1]
        text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt","a")
        text_file.write(string + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

However, every now and then it gives this error because it cannot find my location:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = gps.get_gpgga()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/hardware/gps/l80gps.py", line 119, in get_gpgga
    pkt = self.get_nmea_pkt('GPGGA')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/hardware/gps/l80gps.py", line 293, in get_nmea_pkt
    "Timed out before valid '{}'.".format(pattern))
microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.NMEAPacketNotFoundError: Timed out before valid 'GPGGA'.
```

It's alright to have that error. The trouble I have is that the program stops running if it occurs. Is there a way to catch that error and get the program to loop back and try again even if it encounters this error?

## UPDATE

```
if I try Stefan_Reinhardt's method, I would get the following error instead:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = gps.get_gpgga()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/hardware/gps/l80gps.py", line 119, in get_gpgga
    pkt = self.get_nmea_pkt('GPGGA')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/microstacknode/hardware/gps/l80gps.py", line 293, in get_nmea_pkt
    "Timed out before valid '{}'.".format(pattern))
microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.NMEAPacketNotFoundError: Timed out before valid 'GPGGA'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 10, in <module>
    except NMEAPacketNotFoundError:
NameError: name 'NMEAPacketNotFoundError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree to the answer of Oisin,
but i'd suggest to put the try-except clause only arround the line where it could happen, and pass the rest of the while-loop with a continue statement so it would look like

```
##Prints the latitude and longitude every second.
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
    while True:
        try:
            data = gps.get_gpgga()
        except NMEAPacketNotFoundError:
            continue
        List = [list(data.values())[x] for x in [7, 9, 12]]
        string=str(List)
        string = string[1:-1]
        text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt","a")
        text_file.write(string + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I get this output: `microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.NMEAPacketNotFoundError: Timed out before valid 'GPGGA'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 10, in <module>
    except NMEAPacketNotFoundError:
NameError: name 'NMEAPacketNotFoundError' is not defined `

Comment: Use `microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.NMEAPacketNotFoundError` instead of  `NMEAPacketNotFoundError`. See my Answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it could get stuck in an infinite recursion loop.

```
##Prints the latitude and longitude every second.
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getPos()

def getPos():
    try:
        while True:
            gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
            data = gps.get_gpgga()
            List = [list(data.values())[x] for x in [7, 9, 12]]
            string=str(List)
            string = string[1:-1]
            text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt","a")
            text_file.write(string + "\n")
            time.sleep(1)
    except microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.NMEAPacketNotFoundError:
        getPos()
```